# JDOM - Converting TXT to KML - some details

Tags: java, kml, jdom

I have this .txt file:

> 20480418; -29.761660000,  -51.123630000;  0;  1
>   20479111; -29.761410000,  -51.121220000;  0;  2
>   20476493; -29.764020460,  -51.124986440;  0;  3
>   20472881; -29.762670000,  -51.126950000;  1;  4
>   20479672; -29.767868465,  -51.127055623;  1;  5
>   20479692; -29.744090000,  -51.156210000;  1;  1
>   20476184; -29.746494407,  -51.158303478;  1;  2
>   20479622; -29.746680000,  -51.158340000;  1;  3
>   20479969; -29.739370000,  -51.166900000;  1;  4
>   20474498; -29.737870000,  -51.171300000;  1;  5
>   20479287; -29.748470000,  -51.150200000;  1;  6
>   20480145; -29.746500000,  -51.158300000;  2;  7

Order number; longitude; latitude; priority; service order

Now, i have to transform it in kml and i tried to adapt a tutorial i saw and i did it like that:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.jdom2.Document;
import org.jdom2.Element;
import org.jdom2.Namespace;
import org.jdom2.output.Format;
import org.jdom2.output.XMLOutputter;


public class SistemaRotas {
    static String inputFile = "solucao.txt";
    static String outputFile = "output.kml";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        /*
         * Step 1: gerar XML stub
         */
        Namespace ns = Namespace.getNamespace("", "http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2");
        // kml
        Element kml = new Element("kml", ns);
        Document kmlDocument = new Document(kml);

        // Documento
        Element document = new Element("Document", ns);
        kml.addContent(document);

        // nome + descrição
        Element name = new Element("name", ns);
                Element description = new Element("description", ns);
        name.setText("Visualizacao da solucao");
                description.setText("Visualizacao gerada para acompanhamento da solucao.");
        document.addContent(name);
                document.addContent(description);

        /*
         * Passo 2: colocar estilo dos elementos
         */

        // estilo
        Element style = new Element("Style", ns);
        style.setAttribute("id", "pontoCaramelo");
        document.addContent(style);

        // estiloIcone
        Element iconStyle = new Element("IconStyle", ns);
        iconStyle.addContent(iconStyle);

        // cor
        Element color = new Element("color", ns);
        color.setText("ffAAD9CB");
        iconStyle.addContent(color);

        // icone
        Element icon = new Element("Icon", ns);
        iconStyle.addContent(icon);

        // href
        Element href = new Element("href", ns);
        href.setText("http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/placemark_circle.png");
        icon.addContent(href);

        /*
         * Passo 3: ler informações do arquivo
         * adicionar num Placemark para cada informação do elemento
         */

        File file = new File(inputFile);
        BufferedReader reader;
        try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            try {
                String line = reader.readLine();
                while (line != null) {
                    String[] lineParts = line.split(";");
                    if (lineParts.length == 4) {
                        // add in the Placemark

                        // Placemark
                        Element placemark = new Element("Placemark", ns);
                        document.addContent(placemark);

                                                // número da ordem
                        Element pmOrdem = new Element("name", ns);
                        pmOrdem.setText(lineParts[0].trim());
                        placemark.addContent(pmOrdem);

                                                // styleUrl
                        Element pmStyleUrl = new Element("styleUrl", ns);
                        pmStyleUrl.setText("#pontoCaramelo");
                        placemark.addContent(pmStyleUrl);

                                                // ponto
                        Element pmPonto = new Element("Point", ns);
                        placemark.addContent(pmPonto);

                                                // coordenadas
                        Element pmCoordenadas = new Element("coordinates", ns);
                        pmCoordenadas.setText(lineParts[1].trim());
                        pmPonto.addContent(pmCoordenadas);

                                                // prioridade
                        Element pmPrioridade = new Element("description", ns);
                        pmPrioridade.setText(lineParts[2].trim());
                        placemark.addContent(pmPrioridade);

                                                // ordem de atendimento
                        Element pmAtendimento = new Element("description", ns);
                        pmAtendimento.setText(lineParts[3].trim());
                        placemark.addContent(pmAtendimento);
                    }
                    // ler a próxima linha
                    line = reader.readLine();
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        /*
         * Passo 4: escrever arquivo KML
         */
        try {
            XMLOutputter outputter = new XMLOutputter(Format.getPrettyFormat());
            FileOutputStream writer = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
            outputter.output(kmlDocument, writer);
            //outputter.output(kmlDocument, System.out);
            writer.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

The thing is: i don't know why the order done for the informations isn't working, and i would need the priority and service order to be together in a CDATA type if possible, or at least together in the same information balloon.

Besides i only have it appearing:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
```

And i need that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2" xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
```

Tips? Ideas? Because i'm really confused in what to do to fix it :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made this code that would help you:

```
    Namespace ns = Namespace.getNamespace("", "http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2");
    Namespace ns2 = Namespace.getNamespace("gx", "http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2");

    Element kml = new Element("kml", ns);
    kml.addNamespaceDeclaration(ns2);
    Document kmlDocument = new Document(kml);

    Element folder = new Element("folder");
    Element placemark = new Element("placemark");
    folder.addContent(placemark);

    kmlDocument.getRootElement().addContent(folder);

    XMLOutputter xmlOutput = new XMLOutputter();
    xmlOutput.setFormat(Format.getPrettyFormat());
    xmlOutput.output(kmlDocument, new FileWriter("./prueba.kml"));
```

It's only for the basic structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2">
  <folder xmlns="">
    <placemark />
  </folder>
</kml>
```